# to display name,department name,marks of top performer(s) in Software Engineering,ordered by department name in ascending order

Tags: oracle

Write a query to display the name, department name and marks of the top performer(s)  in Software Engineering , ordered by department name in ascending order.

I have used below query but didn't getting desired result showing me two students from different department with same marks in software engineering

```
select distinct a.student_name,b.department_name,c.value from student a
inner join department b on a.department_id=b.department_id
inner join mark c on c.student_id=a.student_id and c.value in
(select max(a.value) from mark a,subject d where a.subject_id=d.subject_id
and d.subject_name='Software Engineering')
order by b.department_name;
```

[please refer the schema](https://ibb.co/QDnJg7n)

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. Please provide relevant sample data and relationships between tables (if it's not obvious). Since this is homework, please also provide your attempt at solving it.

Comment: @JNevill now I've provided the query I've constructed myself. Please check now.

Comment: Why is your result wrong? The task says "top performer(s)" so it's expecting there could be a tie. Otherwise, how would you choose between the two?

Comment: @AlexPoole I don't know why it is wrong. please refer the schema

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - this part: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation to your problem and Code :**

**1**.By using sub query you only extract maximum number and check if it is present but the value(mark of subject) may be present for other subjects that's why you are having two output instead of one.

**2**.You didn't join the subject table and didn't check if subject is software engineering.

**Solution to the Problem is:**

```
select student_name,department_name,value 
from student 
inner join department using(department_id)
inner join mark using(student_id)
inner join subject using(subject_id)
where value = (select max(value) from mark join subject using(subject_id) where lower(subject_name)='software engineering')
and lower(subject_name)='software engineering'
order by department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This part requires modification:

```
 and c.value in (
   select max(a.value) 
     from mark a, subject d 
     where a.subject_id = d.subject_id and d.subject_name='Software Engineering')
```

You need to take only *Software Engineer* rows from `mark` table, so please write:

```
 and (c.subject_id, c.value) 
     in (select subject_id, max(a.value) 
           from mark a
           join subject d using (subject_id)
           where d.subject_name = 'Software Engineering'
           group by subject_id)
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b5275113bb83c845ecd5451e5f4d686])</sup>**

You can do it also with analitycal funcions (row_number, max), but I wanted to stay close to yours solution, which you know.

Comment: Your solution is giving ambiguous entries. Not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select student_name,department_name,value 
    from Student 
    inner join department using(department_id)
    inner join mark using(student_id)
    inner join subject using(subject_id)
    where value = (select max(value) from mark join subject using(subject_id) where lower(subject_name)='software engineering')
    and lower(subject_name)='software engineering'
    order by department_name;
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed to the original query and why. This is more helpful to understand the reasoning behind changes as opposed to just give the answer.

Answer (score 0):

select student_name, department_name, value from student s join department d
on s.department_id = d.department_id join mark m on s.student_id = s.student_id
join subject su on m.subject_id = su.subject_id where subject_name = 'Software Engineering'
and value= (select max(value) from mark m1 join subject su1 on m1.subject_id = su1.subject_id where subject_name = 'Software Engineering')
order by 2 asc;

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, Please put your SQL code in code-block. you may google for stackoverflow's markdown. second thing. do add some explanation with your code.